# How can you assign keys in tmux without Ctrl-b first?

Tags: bash, tmux

In tmux, we use the trigger key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> followed by an action key. However, I would like to assign *direct* keys in my `.tmux.conf` and was hoping this is possible. I would like to assign <kbd>F7</kbd> (without the need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd>) to start copy mode (i.e. equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> followed by <kbd>[</kbd>) and also to allow <kbd>Esc</kbd> to act in the same way that `q` does when in copy mode (i.e. it drops out of copy mode). So, <kbd>F7</kbd> to enter copy mode and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave copy mode. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tmux has several key-binding *tables*, as [documented](https://man.archlinux.org/man/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS) in `man tmux` under "bind-key". There are several default tables:

- The `root` table is where the prefix key itself is bound.
- The `prefix` table is used after the prefix is pressed, and is the one your usual keybindings go.
- The `copy-mode` table is used in copy mode if *mode-keys* is set to "emacs".
- The `copy-mode-vi` table is used in copy mode if *mode-keys* is set to "vi".

If you want to bind without the prefix key, use the `-n` or `-T root` option to *bind-key*.

---

<kbd>Esc</kbd> might behave slightly weird, as the terminal codes for nearly all special keys (Alt+keys, function keys, arrow keys, etc) also begin with exactly the same Esc. Programs like Vim use a timer to distinguish the two. You may need to lower the *escape-time* parameter in tmux.

Comment: Indeed, I'm having a problem with that. I see that `Escape` is used in tmux `bind-key -T copy-mode Escape send-keys -X cancel` and the listing for `q` is also `bind-key -T copy-mode q                     send-keys -X cancel`, so they are the same by default(!), but `Escape` does not exit copy mode for some reason. I'm just trying to learn tmux for a couple of days, so if you anything you can suggest on implementing `escape-time` parameter would be great and I will give it a try?

Comment: "copy-mode" is for emacs; you want the "copy-mode-vi" table instead. (I'm reading the docs for tmux 3.2.) Generally, I have `set -g escape-time 50`, so that tmux would be faster at forwarding the keypress to Vim.

Comment: I just get `/home/boss/.tmux.conf:13: unknown command: copy-mode-vi` when I try to use this. Sorry, I'm a little confused... what would the command in `.tmux.conf` be do you think for the Escape key?

Comment: It's not a command, it's a table name for bind-key.